# Doctrine 2 issue inside Zf2 Navigation - strange issue

Tags: orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I can use doctrine from all my controller without any problem

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default");
$newsItems = $em->getRepository('Website\Entity\News')->findAll();

foreach($newsItems as $item)
// do stuff here
```

Preamble: if I use Zend\Db\Adapter instead of Doctrine the following work as aspected !

I'm inside a MyNavigationObject that was instanciated by MyNavigationFactory.
I have a mysql table called mainmenu with 4 records: home,news,company,contact

I would like to do my own navigation with Doctrine-Orm.
Also I have an entity called Mainmenu.

I can call the entityManager and the results is composed with 4 records but 4 times the records number 1. Incredible !

this is the code:

```
 protected function getPages(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    if (null === $this->pages) {

        $em = $serviceLocator->get("doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default");
        $menuItems = $em->getRepository('Website\Entity\Mainmenu')->findAll();

        //return default key            
        $configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()] = array();       

        foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem)
        {                       
            $configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()][$menuItem->getName()] = array(
                    'label' => $menuItem->getLabel(),
                    'route' => $menuItem->getRoute(),
                    'controller' => $menuItem->getController(),
            );          
        }

        if (!isset($configuration['navigation'])) {
            throw new \Exception\InvalidArgumentException('Could not find navigation configuration key');
        }
        if (!isset($configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()])) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                    'Failed to find a navigation container by the name "%s"',
                    $this->getName()
            ));
        }

        // refer to Mvc::Application object not to modulename
        $application = $serviceLocator->get('Application');
        $routeMatch  = $application->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        $router      = $application->getMvcEvent()->getRouter();
        $pages       = $this->getPagesFromConfig($configuration['navigation'][$this->getName()]);

        $this->pages = $this->injectComponents($pages, $routeMatch, $router);
    }
    return $this->pages;
```

Can anyone provide suggestions or reproduce the issue ?

bye

Comment: Solved: tinyint field will be evaluted always bool from doctrine